# None type variable can be "filled" in pygame

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I am learning pygame and have been following [this tutorial.](https://pythonspot.com/snake-with-pygame/)

There seems to be a problem:

- I define in the __ init __ a variable -> `_display_surf = None` ...
- in order to  make this command:  `self._display_surf.fill((0,0,0))`
  to render a black background.

Nevertheless, I get this error:

```
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "snake.py", line 86, in <module>
   theApp.on_execute()
  File "snake.py", line 79, in on_execute
   self.on_render()
  File "snake.py", line 49, in on_render
   self._display_surf.fill((0,0,0))
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fill'
```

Hence my question: **what type should the variable I declare ?**

Comment: It means from place, where you run "self._display_surf.fill((0,0,0))" fill does not exist. It may be the reason you haven't imported it correctly. Also edit your post to show this place in your code, otherwise we can only guess, what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`self.on_init()` in the __ init __ does the work: the variables changes to a pygame.Surface()